# disable textfield editing without blocking the clear button

Tags: ios, swift3, uitextfield, swift4

do you know how I can make an edittext get non-editable for the user, but allow it to use the textfield's own clearbutton to delete it?

I tried using the:

```
textField.isEnabled = false
```

and

```
textField.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

but it did not work very well because it disables everything

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Return `false` from the text field delegate’s `textFieldShouldBeginEditing`.

Comment: Thank you very much, extremely grateful :D

Comment: noice mate !!!!